# Php get string after x characters

Tags: php, string, path

I have an array which returns me paths like these:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\app\storage\app/img/img24.png"  


C:\xampp\htdocs\app\storage\app/img/img3.png"
```

I need to extract the number from those parts, in this case 24 and 3 and save them into another array. So far I extracted the length like this:

```
$pathLen = strlen(storage_path('app/img/'));
```

That returned me 45, but I dont know how to continue

Comment: Why have have tagged laravel, mysql in a question related to php?

Comment: You can use substr

Comment: It was cached from another question I wanted to post I changed it sry

Comment: Have you tried with preg_match ?

Comment: You would have to find the position of something that is always present right before what you are looking for (like `/img/img`), and then use substring functions. Will become problematic, if you don’t know beforehand how long that number might be. Instead of using plain old string functions, you might consider using a simple regular expression, that can perform this task easily.

Comment: regex will be helpful here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get substr from the last `/`, then use intval() to get the int. [Live demo](https://eval.in/816147).

```
<?php
$string = "C:\xampp\htdocs\app\storage\app/img/img24.png";
echo intval(substr($string, strrpos($string, '/') +4));
```

Comment: This answer is good, as it's not dependent on the path (which could change).

Comment: how would you create a conditions which checks if the number is 0 if ist 0 Change it to an empty string

Comment: `$value = intval(substr($string, strrpos($string, '/') +4)); $value = $value == 0 ? '' : $value;`

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match('~img/img(.*?).png~', $arrayinput, $output);

print_r($output[1]);
```